# “Cannot find proj.db” and "ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: cannot build geodeticCRS 4326" errors

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, macos

Updated to QGIS 3.16 recently, when I try to reproject from the datafiles CRS EPSG:4326 - WG 84 to EPSG:32718 - WG84/UTM zone 18S I get this error

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db

ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:

EPSG:32718
```

I am using macOS and I updated to by downloading software from the website https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html - the latest release

I have located the `proj.db` in my computer `C:/Users/anaconda3/envs/gsa_sm2019/share/proj/proj.db`
and tried to change the setting environment.

I tried

> import os os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] =
> 'C:/Users/anaconda3/envs/gsa_sm2019/share/proj'
> os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = 'C:/Users/anaconda3/envs/gsa_sm2019/share'
> import gdal

Reprojected again, this is the new error received:

> ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: cannot build geodeticCRS
> 4326: SQLite error on SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name,
> ellipsoid_code, prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code,
> area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated
> FROM geodetic_datum WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column:
> publication_date
> ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
> EPSG:4326

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: What operating system are you using? how did you update to 3.16?

Comment: I am using macOS and I updated to by downloading software from the website https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html - the latest release

Comment: please use the [edit] link to update your question with this information

Comment: I've updated the question with the info now - thanks

Comment: Proj needs to find proj.db file. PROJ_LIB environmental variable should be set point to the directory where the file is. See old answers https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=proj.db.

Answer (score 8):

I believe PROJ_LIB should be set to the directory where proj.db lives, not the file itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I did this and it got a different error (see above)

Comment: Is your proj.db from the same version as your library?

see, e.g.: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-Issues-with-CRS-in-QGIS-master-on-Ubuntu-20-04-tp5439192p5439194.html

Comment: not sure - I have a few proj.db in anaconda3. The other paths are /Users/heatherneedham/anaconda3/pkgs/proj4-6.1.0-h2cc77ee_2/share/proj/proj.db, /Users/anaconda3/pkgs/proj4-6.1.0-h2cc77ee_2/share/proj/proj.db - which I think are different versions to the proj.db in the gsa_sm2019 environment

Comment: do you have a GDAL install folder? Mine is 'C:\Program Files\GDAL\projlib'. In my script is: `os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'C:\Program Files\GDAL\projlib'`

Comment: I got this error opening a shapefile with geopandas after having installed postgis on a database.  Like others, postgis changed the system environmental variable, which caused the error.  But I still need that to work properly, so I didn't want to change that.  Using `os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] =pyproj.datadir.get_data_dir()` in my python code worked to load the data without changing the env var.

Comment: @AaronBramson 's answer solves that exact situation and should be promoted as the correct answer to OP

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when trying to use `ogr2ogr` on a shapefile, whilst setting `-a_srs "EPSG:27700"`. The error you mention was very similar to mine, and I realised that my install of PostgreSQL/PostGIS had created its own gdal folder and set my system environment variables to look in the PostgreSQL gdal install folder, not my seperate standalone GDAL installation folder.

To fix, I removed all references to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\gdal-data` & the postgres proj_lib folder etc from my system environment variables, making sure that ONLY the standalone GDAL paths were set instead. ie. `C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data` etc.

Comment: Worked for me! https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413943/failed-to-process-srs-definition-error-when-reprojecting-vector-layer-via-ogr2 My 'Path' System Variable included `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin`. I just removed it and I can run `ogr2ogr -t_srs` with no error. Thanks!

Comment: @LeeGoddard I don't think it should be empty. It needs to point to the GDAL directory.

Comment: @TheoF Yes, indeed!