# "Failed to process SRS definition" error when reprojecting vector layer via ogr2ogr

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, ogr2ogr, proj, sqlite

I'm using GDAL 3.3.1 with all the necessary variables already setup.

I'm reprojecting a vector layer using ogr2ogr `ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:32651 test.shp new_layer.shp` and an error says

> ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: SQLite error on SELECT name, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, geodetic_crs_auth_name, geodetic_crs_code, conversion_auth_name, conversion_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM projected_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name

> ERROR 1: Failed to process SRS definition: EPSG:32651

A similar question was asked already but not entirely the same with my problem [“Cannot find proj.db” and "ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: cannot build geodeticCRS 4326" errors](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378463/cannot-find-proj-db-and-error-1-proj-proj-create-from-database-cannot-buil)

Comment: See comment in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383883/pyproj-invalid-projection-init-epsg25832 `You're likely  using a PROJ < 8 library with a proj.db from PROJ 7.2 or 8. Check PROJ_LIB`.

Comment: Thank you! I hope the fix is an easy one.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this? I just upgraded my proj to 8.1.1 via OSGEO4W installer (https://proj.org/install.html) and the same error shows. The link you sent me does not have a solution but rather only the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind. Solved it thanks to this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/394320/146811

Comment: You must have also an older version of Proj somewhere in your system. Proj 8 does not query the  area_of_use_auth_name field.