# ogr2org SHP file to SQLSserver Failed to process SRS definition

Tags: ogr2ogr, epsg, srid

I am having issues importing a SHP file into SQLServer. The SHP file is EPSG 28354 (drawn in QGIS 3.x) and has these assoc files:

- REE_ProjectAreas.cpg
- REE_ProjectAreas.dbf
- REE_ProjectAreas.prj
- REE_ProjectAreas.shp
- REE_ProjectAreas.shx

The **ogr2ogr.exe** I am using is from ***OSGeo4w v  3.3.1*** (from https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w) which installed itself into *c:\OSGeo4w*

the two Windows commands I am using are:

```
call c:\OSGeo4W\bin\o4w_env.bat

c:\OSgeo4w\bin\ogr2ogr.exe  -progress -f MSSQLSpatial  "MSSQL:server=HSLT_17;database=REE_DHSS;trusted_connection=yes"  "c:\temp\REE_ProjectAreas.shp"  -a_srs "ESPG:28354"
```

The error I get is:

`ERROR 1: Failed to process SRS definition: ESPG:28354`

if I remove the *-a_srs "ESPG:28354"* part then the SHP file gets imported but the SRID is incorrect in the assoc SQL tables that ogr2ogr creates and populates:
[image]
[image]

the contents of the *o4w_env.bat* is:

```
REM Make parent of this script location our current directory,
REM converting UNC path to drive letter if needed
pushd %~dp0
cd ..

REM set OSGEO4W_ROOT to short path version
for %%i in ("%CD%") do set OSGEO4W_ROOT=%%~fsi

REM start with clean path
set path=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%WINDIR%\system32;%WINDIR%;%WINDIR%\WBem
for %%f in ("%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\etc\ini\*.bat") do call "%%f"

popd
```

After running that the path is pretty clean:

*PATH=c:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\WBem*

The contents of the *REE_ProjectAreas.prj* is:

`PROJCS["GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_54",GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994",DATUM["D_GDA_1994",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",141.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

i found:

*[“Cannot find proj.db” and "ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: cannot build geodeticCRS 4326" errors](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378463/cannot-find-proj-db-and-error-1-proj-proj-create-from-database-cannot-buil/394320#394320)*

but that is not quite the same. I am setting my path to be clean and only use c:\OSGeo4W\bin

Also tried ogr2ogr from within *C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin*, same problem.

Why does ogr2ogr not import the SHP into SQL with the correct EPSG?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your command, it should be:

```
c:\OSgeo4w\bin\ogr2ogr.exe  -progress -f MSSQLSpatial  "MSSQL:server=HSLT_17;database=REE_DHSS;trusted_connection=yes"  "c:\temp\REE_ProjectAreas.shp"  -a_srs "EPSG:28354"
```

That's **EPSG** not ESPG

Comment: duh, sorry, my bad. good catch ... works now.